# Cannot connect to MS Access file from SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have been trying for the past week or so to import data programmatically to a SQL Server 2008 table from a Microsoft Access .mdb file. I have been getting nothing but errors, and solving one just reveals another. I made the file into a linked server, and now when I try to query it with:

```
Select * from OPENQUERY(Importdata, 'Select * from [IMBPieceBC]')
```

I get the error:

```
OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "Importdata" returned message "Cannot open database ''.  It may not be a database that your application recognizes, or the file may be corrupt.".
Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "Importdata".
```

I've read several suggestions to relink dlls in the registry, but I've done that, and I'm still getting the error. Is there anything else I can do to fix it, or at least figure out what is wrong?

Migrating the data to a SQL Server instance is not an option. The mdb files are generated by a third-party program, so there's nothing we can do about it.

Comment: Previously this problem has been due to permissions, for me, it was as simple as running my sql server express service logged on to the local system account, you will need something better: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2008/07/23/ole-db-provider-microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0-for-linked-server-null-returned-message-unspecified-error.aspx

Comment: @Remou The error message in your link was the error message I was getting before this one. I fixed it by changing some setting, can't remember what by now, and restarting the server. The service is already running under the LocalSystem account.

Comment: Is installing the free MS Access ACE drivers an option for you? http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734

Comment: I've read that those won't work for an mdb file. Was that not true?

Comment: ACE drivers are backward compatible. I can even read mdbs with 64 bit 2010 drivers. Furthermore, they will not interfere with your existing Jet drivers. they are referred to in a different way.

Comment: @Remou - IT WORKED! Oh, this is wonderful. This is an extremely important part of our software, and it has been getting very frustrating. If you'll put that down as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: It's somewhat slow though, on the order of around 80k records a minute. Is there any way to make it transfer faster?

Comment: Are you transferring to an indexed table?

Comment: Hmm, no, it doesn't look like it's indexed.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation at my workplace - a third party application that maintains data in MDBs, but other applications needing access to it.  How I've done it is that this 'intermediary' application has links to the SQL Server tables and the MDB tables.  You could use either a query or a VBA written form event to transfer information from the MDB table(s) involved into your corresponding SQL Server tables using a INSERT INTO query, fitted with a SELECT FROM subquery providing the values being inserted.

Comment: I'm not quite sure you read the question. That's exactly what I'm trying to do, and I'm getting an error. The question was how to fix the error, not how to do it in the first place.

Comment: @SaintWacko - I didn't recognize the code you wrote as being the same as mine, hence my confusion.  I also didn't see any mention of an 'intermediary'.  I didn't set out to be dumb on purpose.  Is it possible that your syntax is incorrect?  Can you read both tables (the vendor-created MDB and the SQL Server table?) using simple SELECT statements?

Comment: All my code here is doing is trying to query from a linked server which is actually an Access database, just to see if I can get the connection working. We tried doing it from the Access end, but it's far too slow. I can, of course, read/write to the SQL table, as this code is running on the server, but the problem occurs when I try to read the MDB.